# Decimal.ToUInt64 "Value was either too large or too small for a UInt64

Tags: c#, type-conversion, decimal, uint64

I am doing: -

```
Decimal production = 0;
Decimal expense = 5000;

Decimal.ToUInt64(production - expense);
```

But it throws exception with the following error message.

`"Value was either too large or too small for a UInt64"`

Can someone give me a workaround for this.

**Thanks!**

### Edit

In any case, I want the result as a positive number.

Comment: It's a negative number

Comment: -1: Missing details on desired outcome: How do you want -5000 to be represented in unsigned number????

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem: -5000m is a negative number, which is outside the range of `UInt64` (an *unsigned* type).

Solution: use `Int64` instead of `UInt64` if you want to cope with negative numbers.

Note that you can just cast instead of calling `Decimal.To...`:

```
long x = (long) (production - expense);
```

Alternative: validate that the number is non-negative before trying to convert it, and deal with it however you deem appropriate.

Very dodgy alternative: if you *really* just want the absolute value (which seems unlikely) you could use [`Math.Abs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4ke8e73.aspx):

```
UInt64 alwaysNonNegative = Decimal.ToUInt64(Math.Abs(production - expense));
```

Comment: basically I want the result in a positive number

Comment: @WaqasRaja: But the result *isn't* a positive number! Do you really want `production=0, expense=5000` to have the same result as `production=5000, expense=0`? That sounds *very, very* odd.

Comment: actually it is the part of a complex formula, and I need the result of subtraction as a positive number

Comment: @WaqasRaja: You didn't answer the question - do you *really* want the results of those two very different situations to be the same? If so, see my edit and use `Math.Abs`. But that seems very unlikely to be appropriate. Fundamentally, the result of subtracting 5000 from 0 *isn't* a positive number. It just isn't. Now, what result did you want from this, and why?

Answer (score 0):

0 - 5000 will return -5000. And you are trying to convert to an unsigned int which can not take negative values.

Try changing it to signed int

```
Decimal.ToInt64(production - expense);
```

Answer (score 0):

UInt can not store negative numbers. The result of your calculation is negative. That's why the error comes. Check the sign before using ToUInt64 and correct it via *-1 or use a signed Int64.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
var result = Decimal.ToInt64(production - expense);
```